# which of the following statement is Trues

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $ R = \mathbb{F}_2[X]$. which of the following statement is True

$a)$  Every  maximal Ideal of $R$  has infinitely  many elements

$b)$ For  every postive intger $n$,every ideal of $R$ has only finitely many element of degreee $ \le n$

My attempt  :  option a) will  be true because  Polynomial  Ring has infinitely many elements    and  opton b)  will be false as same  logic  ihave taken in  option $a)$

Is  Its  correct ????

Any/hints  soluton will be appreciated

thanks u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (a), if $f \in \mathfrak{m}$, then $f,Xf,X^2f, \ldots \in \mathfrak{m}$, and they have different degrees, so you have found infinitely many elements.

For part (b), in $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$, there are only finitely many elements of degree $\leq n$.

Comment: one more   doubts  ???   How  can  u  said  that  $X^2f $  is  maximal  ?

Comment: $X^2 f$ is an element in the ideal, because $f$ is. (I did not use maximality at all.)

Comment: thanks u @dalbouvet